# Firefox DB doesn't include the latest bookmarks

Tags: firefox-for-android, bookmarks

I've located the browser.db (\data\data\apps\org.mozilla.firefox\files\mozilla\%$#!.default), but opening it and looking at the "Bookmarks" table doesn't show the latest bookmarks.
Seems like the bookmarks created today (a few hours ago) are not in the table.
Is there another place holding "recent" bookmarks?

Comment: Did you try checking after restarting app (closing and then launching)?

Comment: @beeshyams, that seems to do the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Good you can post the solution yourself - it may help others in future