# Where are Firefox bookmark and history files stored?

Tags: backup, file-management, firefox-for-android

And what are the names? I want to copy each in the event of device failure.

Sync is apparently not an option as the Sync "application" has returned "'Cannot connect to network" for several weeks, and the web page to create an account just has a swirl that never loads anything else.

I'm not sold on sharing data with mozilla anyway, tho if anyone knows how to do that, also, ...

All the tutorials I've found online are about desktop. I tried applying solutions there to android, like searching for 'places.sqlite', but no dice.

I'm running OS 5.1.1, unrooted. I've got two 3rd-party file managers, and of course Firefox lets one browse root directories (file:///...).

Thanks.

Edit: I'm trying to use xBrowserSync, but every version I've found won't install, has this problem:

[image]

[image]

I scanned each at    VirusTotal first, of course.

Comment: Some related questions regarding [bookmark](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/173215) and [history](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/158343) mention the location, but it needs root access to internal storage. I'm not sure if Firefox could browse to that location though.

Comment: Clear cahche of Firefox app and backup whole `/data/data/org.mozilla.firefox/` directory (better using `tar`). It preserves everything including history, bookmarks, tabs and sync account. Set proper UID and SELinux context on restore.

Comment: @Irfan Latif Is there a specific way to "back up"? I'm not a programmer, so I'm a little lost on your restoration advice. Would there be a way to convert to text file, maybe? 

Anyone know what's up with Stync?

This seems overly complicated, but then they can't spy on you when you can DIY.

Comment: @Andrew T. The only place Firefox can't access is the "root" of external storage. 

I am, however, having a problem "downloading," getting "File could not be saved." My file managers show file:///data as empty (one shows its own folder only) and copy it so. (In fact, I'd gone there first and it was that emptiness that caused me to come here.)